# Crawling links in a div

Tags: python, request, web-crawler, beautifulsoup

I am making a web crawler in Python using Beautiful Soup. I want to get links from a certain div, the code I have now does not print anything.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'https://thenewboston.com/'
        source = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source.text
        obj = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html5lib")

        for link in obj.find_all('div', {'class': 'videos-top-courses'}):
            href = 'https://thenewboston.com/', link.get('href')
            print(href)
        page += 1

spider(1)
```

Comment: Look answer in this link I hope it can help you = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390593/scrapy-crawl-and-follow-links-within-href

Comment: `<div>` doesn't have `href` - you have to find `<a>`

Comment: there is no ('div', {'class': 'videos-top-courses'}),check the source code

Comment: Looking at the HTML at the URL you are accessing, there are no `<div>`s with that class -- only `<table>` elements, so your `find_all` call is (correctly) returning no elements.

Comment: there is no `<div>` with `class="videos-top-courses"`. There is `<table>` with `class="videos-top-courses"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find `<table>` instead of `<div>` and later you can find `<a>` to get `href`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'https://thenewboston.com/'
        source = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source.text
        obj = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html5lib")

        for table in obj.find_all('table', {'class': 'videos-top-courses'}):
            for a in table.find_all('a'):
                print(a.get('href'))
        page += 1

spider(1)
```

Comment: That works and is closer to what I wanted but it prints out 3 of the same link.

Comment: That's  why I used `video-icon-column` as class

Comment: there are 3 `<a>` in every video description - (1) in image, (2) in header, (3) in number of videos below description. You have to use other arguments in `find_all` to get only one `<a>`  - see other answer - or use index [0] to get only one `<a>` - ie. `a = table.find_all('a')[0]`

Comment: When I do that it prints out one link a bunch of times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen("https://thenewboston.com/"),'html.parser')
videos = soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'video-icon-column'})
for td in videos:
    print td.a['href']
```